# @Context does not inject the required object in EJB?

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I am trying to implement a simple interceptor that is used to intercept a call to an EJB service class. However I want to inject the HttpServletReques like this :

```
public class Interceptor {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;


    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext context) { 
    // ... 
  } 
}
```

However servletRequest is always null ? any Idea or help ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't this is possible because EJB is not aware of any HTTP requests being made so injecting it into EJB (or it's interceptor) wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Well take a look at this post http://www.mastertheboss.com/resteasy/resteasy-interceptors-tutorial/page-2 

And it you are right, then how do I log http request information that compes to my EJB ?

Comment: But RESTeasy is not en EJB, see the package of the Context `javax.ws.rs.core.Context`

Comment: You will have to pass it through method parameter to your EJB, I am not sure if there is an other way of doing this